# Yii2 Swiftmailer - как задать отправителя по умолчанию?

Tags: yii2

Использую в проекте Yii2, в котором настраиваю отправку писем через родной для него Swiftmailer. Для указания отправителя можно использовать setFrom(). Но каждый раз при отправке писем делать одно и тоже, указывать одного и того отправителя неудобно. Возможно ли один раз, через конфиг указать отправителя, который будет подставляться по умолчанию при каждой отправки писем?

Answer (score 2):

Отправителя также можно указать в конфиге приложения `\config\web.php`

```
...
'components' => [
    ...
    'mailer' => [
        ...
        'messageConfig' => [
            ...
            'from' => ['noreply@site.com' => 'Site Name'],
            ...
        ],
    ...
    ],
    ...
]
...
```

При этом, не нужно будет каждый раз при отправке письма указывать отправителя, он подставиться автоматически, т.е. будет взят из этого конфига.

Подробнее о нюансах работы со Swiftmailer можно почитать тут: http://atoumus.github.io/yii2-swiftmailer.html.